# PostgreSQL 9.5 Using ident in pg_hba

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I am working on a local network based on Windows, and I would like to use the account system of the network to allow users to connect to my DB.

As I understand the proper way is to set the pg_hba method on "ident" as such :

```
host    all    all    10.0.0.0/8      ident
```

But when I do so I get a message saying

```
"Error connecting to the server: FATAL: ident authentication failed for user <user>"
```

As far as I can think of it, my guess is that there could be two problems :
- I do not properly set the pg_hba.
- The role I created does not match the ident found by the server.

In the first case, could you tell if the syntax is correct ? I tried to add "sameuser" after the ident, but it corrupt my pg_hba, and also map=sameuser, but I get the same error as mentionned.

In the second case, I am using a batch run on every session to get the users names like

```
find /c "%username%"
```

or the Python3.6 function os.getlogin(), which produce the same result.

How does PostgreSQL get its "ident" ? And more importantly, how can I reproduce this process to know the idents of the sessions that PostgreSQL will recognize ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

after reading [ident.conf manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-username-maps.html) and using the example from [hba_file manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), I set this up:

```
postgres=# create user ident_user_db;
CREATE ROLE
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ sudo tail -n 1 /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
host    all             all             192.168.8.0/24          ident   map=vao_ident
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ sudo tail -n 1 /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_ident.conf
vao_ident         vao           ident_user_db
```

Now I'm connecting from same machine to its external IP:

```
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ psql -h 192.168.8.107 -U ident_user_db
```

> ```
> psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "ident_user_db"
> FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "ident_user_db"
> ```

Seems familiar. Though I followed manual. Last thing to check:

```
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ telnet localhost 113
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

So nothing provides my identity. As advised [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/406606/postgres-error-message-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user)

```
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ sudo apt-get install oidentd
...
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ telnet localhost 113
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

so try now:

```
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ psql -h 192.168.8.107 -U ident_user_db -d vao
psql (9.6.3)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. Unfortunately, if I understand correctly by the presence of "sudo" in your code, this would work for a linux environment. In my case I am working in a full Windows one, so it seems I cannot use your answer... (and I happenned to have read in my searches  that maybe the ident protocol may not be available for Windows...)

Comment: https://www.google.lt/search?espv=2&q=Windows+Ident+Server&oq=Windows+Ident+Server&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30k1l3.787.787.0.1678.1.1.0.0.0.0.98.98.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.1.97.beVICgkCXkw some of them in google search